# How to suppress `gcloud compute firewall-rules update` output when there are no errors?

Tags: gcloud, stderr

I have a bash script running as cron job which has some gcloud commands in it.

eg.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update allow-ssh--source-ranges=$(echo "${mylocations[@]}" | tr ' ' ',')
```

I have the crontab entry redirecting stdout to /dev/null, so that I don't get emails every time it runs.

The problem is that gcloud's output goes to stderr, even when there is no error, so I get emails like this:

> TITLE: Cron user@host /home/user/bin/firewall-update.sh >/dev/null
>
> Updated
> [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name-4234534/global/firewalls/allow-ssh].
>
> ...

I have tried adding `--verbosity=error`, `critical` and `none`to the gcloud commands, but they have no effect.

So how do I stop gcloud from sending this message to stderr when it completes successfully? Why does it even do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add this global flag, which applies to all gcloud commands:

```
--no-user-output-enabled

    Print user intended output to the console. 
    Overrides the default core/user_output_enabled property value for this command invocation. 
    Use --no-user-output-enabled to disable.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--user-output-enabled

Actual errors are still directed to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, it do that, because, you redirect in /dev/null ONLY stdout.
Cron also would send you emails if there are some errors.
Try to redirect in /dev/null stderr too.
Add in the end of your crontab command something like that:

`> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I should have made it clearer, but I do not want to redirect all stderr, as I want to be informed of errors, but glcloud is directing to stderr when no error occurs.